# Amazon S3: Delete empty buckets using Lifecycle

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using [`aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel) to create buckets and store content. With each bucket created, I add a lifecycle using [`putBucketLifecycle()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketLifecycle) to have it automatically deleted after 7 days, like this:

```
$s3->putBucketLifecycle([
    'Bucket'    => $bucket,
    'Rules'     => [
        [
            'Expiration' => 7,
            'ID'         => 'expires-after-7-days--' . uniqid(),
            'Prefix'     => '',
            'Status'     => 'Enabled',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

And it works well... sort of. After 7 days, in fact, all *files* in the bucket are cleared. But strange enough, the *bucket* itself persists. As a result, my S3 is now full of empty buckets:

[image: Empty buckets]
[Image source](http://thecouponproject.com/urban-gardening/)

So the question is, how can I set the buckets to remove themselves also? Am I missing some paremeter/configuration? Or need I call `deleteBucket()` explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buckets do not delete themselves.  Lifecycle policies only apply to objects in the bucket, in spite of the name "bucket lifecycle."

Comment: What a shame... Guess I'll have to come up with my own logic then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only delete objects inside bucket using `putBucketLifecycle()` as Lifecycle rule applies to the objects inside bucket.

Once all the objects inside bucket are deleted (after expiration) you can use following calls to delete the bucket

```
// check if bucket is empty
$s3->listObjects(...);
// or use ListObjects iterator
$s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucket));
// delete bucket if its empty
$s3->deleteBucket(...);
```